# Nginx PHP-fpm permission

Tags: linux, nginx, php, permissions, php-fpm

When i'm setting the user in nginx.conf to root root:

```
user  root root;
```

then my website is working, but when i set it to nginx nginx i get error in the logs:

> connect() to unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock failed (13: Permission denied)

i'm using PHP-FPM 5.5, and i made sure the folder owner is nginx + executing permission are enabled.

what am i missing..?
Thx

-----------------EDIT:

quick edit when changing php-fpm.sock permissions manually it's working. how do i start php-hpm with the right permissions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two bugs opened recently related to this issue:

- [#67244 Wrong owner:group for listening unix socket](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67244)
- [#67175   Change to the default listen.mode setting](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67175)

I personally experience the first one on FreeBSD with php version 5.4.30.
For a workaround I applied both parameters available to specify the owner of the socket like this:

```
[default]
listen = /tmp/php-fastcgi.sock
user = www
group = www
listen.owner = www
listen.group = www
listen.mode = 0660
```

Comment: yeap found it a while ago :)

Answer (score 4):

Check [official documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php). You can use `listen.owner` or `user` to specify the owner of unix socket.

> **listen.owner** string
>
> Set permissions for unix socket, if one is used.
>   In Linux, read/write permissions must be set in order to allow
>   connections from a web server. Many BSD-derived systems allow
>   connections regardless of permissions. Default values: user and group
>   are set as the running user, mode is set to 0666.
>
> **listen.group** string
>
> See listen.owner.
>
> **user** string
>
> Unix user of FPM processes. This option is mandatory.
>
> **group** string
>
> Unix group of FPM processes. If not set, the default
>   user's group is used.

Comment: that was it....in AWS RedHat 6.4 Image the default was 0660 for some reason... i changed it and it worked, thx.